# could not find implicit value for parameter sz: org.scalatest.enablers.Size[akka.Done]

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

what implicit parameter should I add and How ?

I've already tried to add:

```
  implicit val sz = Size;
```

But it's not working.

```
    val done = Consumer
    .committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(topic))
    .map(msg => messageHandler(msg))
    .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.both)
    .mapMaterializedValue(DrainingControl.apply)
    .run()

  Await.result(done.drainAndShutdown(), 5.seconds) should have size 20
```

Throws:

```
errors: Error:(85, 68) could not find implicit value for parameter sz: org.scalatest.enablers.Size 
[akka.Done] Await.result(done.drainAndShutdown(), 5.seconds) should have size 20 

Error:(85, 68) not enough arguments for method size: (implicit sz: org.scalatest.enablers.Size
[akka.Done])org.scalatest.Assertion. Unspecified value parameter sz. Await.result(done.drainAndShutdown(), 5.seconds) should have size 20
```

Comment: errors: Error:(85, 68) could not find implicit value for parameter sz: org.scalatest.enablers.Size[akka.Done]
      Await.result(done.drainAndShutdown(), 5.seconds) should have size 20

________________________________________________________________________________________

Error:(85, 68) not enough arguments for method size: (implicit sz: org.scalatest.enablers.Size[akka.Done])org.scalatest.Assertion.
Unspecified value parameter sz.
      Await.result(done.drainAndShutdown(), 5.seconds) should have size 20

Comment: The error is telling you that you don't have an implicit parameter in scope to define the size of an object of type akka.Done. You will need to supply an implicit of type Size[akka.Done]. Example here: http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/enablers/Size.html